# How is the scrolling in mobile browsers (touch) different from desktop browsers?

Tags: mobile, iphone, safari, android, ipad

I know scrolling works differently on mobile devices since they don't fire the `scroll` event right away.

What else is different? Where can I learn more about it? I want to know if it has any other limitations.

Did anyone give a name to this kind of scrolling?

Comment: Perhaps the mobile browsers actually render the entire page (top to bottom) and only show whatever is visible in proportion to the width (meaning, it would render as if the monitor could fit everything on one window, but the 'scrolling' is actually panning on the display rather than the website).

Comment: That would make sense, although I think it only renders part of the page since at some point you'll start to see empty blocks (on low-ram devices)

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find anything either about this, but the one thing I can assume is that because the mobile screen is much smaller that the scroll speed is probably faster, e.g. if you do a big long swipe on the mobile vs a swipe on the desktop it wouldn't scroll as fast because there is less data to scroll.